# See and edit similar lines within the same file

Tags: linux

How to see duplicate lines (copy/past of part of a text) *within the same file*? I have a file where there are many copy/pasted parts. Sometime, it's just a couple of lines. Sometime, it's a line, but there are extra character at the end or beginning.

I've search, but to no avail:
There are some tools that exists to increase a developer's code quality that checks for similar parts of code between files. BUT in this instance, it is within the *same file*.

It needs to have an interface to easily see and edit/remove the lines.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Windows or Linux or Mac?

Comment: @harrymc, He has tagged linux, I think he or she need a linux solution

Answer (score 0):

If there are any extra charactes at the beginning and/or end of the lines,
they should first be removed.

For simple lines, use the
[uniq command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html),
where the interesting options for you are:

```
-d, --repeated
          only print duplicate lines, one for each group

-D     print all duplicate lines

--all-repeated[=METHOD]
          like -D, but allow separating groups with an empty line;
          METHOD={none(default),prepend,separate}
```

Example usage:

```
uniq -D file
```

For more tricks, see the post
[Find duplicate lines in a file and count how many time each line was duplicated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712437/find-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-and-count-how-many-time-each-line-was-duplicated)

Comment: It doesn't answer exactly the question (I think nothing could), but it'll help :)